# How to test a function call from a different module

Tags: testing, elixir

There are probably lots of similar questions here but I still don't understand how it's done.

Let's say I have the following trivial module:

```elixir
defmodule ModuleOne do

  def do_something(argument) do
    argument
    |> do_first_thing()
    |> do_second_thing()
    |> ModuleTwo.do_something()
  end

end
```

Now, I have `ModuleTwo` covered with tests so it doesn't make sense to duplicate that testing logic. Also it's not `Twitter API` module or something of the kind so I dont think it's a good idea to come up with a compile-time mock module ( as far as I can see, it's a good idea in case cases, like HTTP calls but doing that for every external module call will obviously turn into a mess ) and also I don't want to pass a function as an argument just for the sake of testing ( especially if I have calls to multiple external modules ) because it messes up the interface with unnecessary things.

Also people suggest not to use mocks, like the `meck` library, which is the most obvious decision here, but I don't understand why ...

Anyway, what would be a good way to test this module considering all the suggestions above?

Thank you

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. You admit to having tests that cover `ModuleTwo`, so why not just write a test for what you expect `ModuleOne.do_something/1` to do?

Comment: @JustinWood Because testing in a black box manner causes tests duplication because I'd need to test that `ModuleOne.do_something/1` does what is done by `ModuleTwo.do_something/1`

Comment: But you get that. You already have full tests around your other module. So now you just need to make sure that this function does what it is supposed to do. If `ModuleOne.do_something/1` only called `ModuleTwo.do_something/1` then I would agree that there is duplication. However, since there is more going on than calling a single function, there is no duplication.

Comment: Basically it boils down to this. By your logic, you should not write any tests for your application. This is because, at the end of the day, all code is written using external modules given to us by the language itself and all of that is properly tested. In reality, we need to write tests to make sure that the way we stitch our code together, the functions give us the output we expect.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be:

1) Don't call the `ModuleTwo` in `ModuleOne` at all. Then test only the transformation before. And move the `ModuleTwo` call to the caller code or other "integration" module. Then test the caller code/integration model separately on integration level.

2) Use `meck` to test that `ModuleTwo` has been called with the argument you expect. But it is then similar to 1) as it practically test the 2 transformation steps.

Comment: I agree with (1). Don't call ModuleTwo in ModuleOne. Instead, do `ModuleOne.do_something() |> ModuleTwo.do_something()`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Lukáš Doležal. Don't call `ModuleTwo.do_something()` in `ModuleOne.do_something()`. The ideal is to have small functions that perform one task well. So, ideally you would do `ModuleOne.do_something() |> ModuleTwo.do_something()` instead.

However, sometimes the things that are *ideal* are not *practical*. Without context here we won't know. If that is the case, and you really want to cover everything with zero duplication, then there is a compromise that might work for you:

#### Instead of:

```elixir
defmodule ModuleOne do

  def foo(bar) do
    bar
    |> first()
    |> second()
    |> ModuleTwo.foo()
  end

end
```

#### Do:

```elixir
defmodule ModuleOne do

  def foo(bar), do: do_foo(bar) |> ModuleTwo.foo()

  def do_foo(bar) do
    bar
    |> first()
    |> second()
  end

end
```

And then just test `ModuleOne.do_foo/1` instead of `ModuleOne.foo/1`